# nft_pipapo_avx2_scratch_index shows up on all my perf recordings

Tags: linux, hotspot, nftables, perf

I'm investigating a performance issue on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS machine. I take the following steps:

```sh
sudo perf record -g -F max -s --call-graph dwarf -e cycles -e sched:sched_switch --switch-events --sample-cpu
```

Then open the recording with `sudo hotspot`:

[image: HotSpot showing nft_pipapo_avx2_scratch_index]

I realize that probably this is not very accurate of a measurement, because it collected only 719 samples over 2 seconds. However...

[image: Timeline of HotSpot]

The timeline suggests that the CPU was spending quite some time in process #0, which is the kernel I assume.

When looking at the Top Down view in HotSpot, we can see that this `nft_pipapo_avx2_scratch_index` pops in pretty much everywhere.

[image: Top Down]

Reading about what this thing is, it seems to be part of the netfilter project nf_tables:

```c
/* PIPAPO: PIle PAcket POlicies: set for arbitrary concatenations of ranges
```

Defined here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/netfilter/nft_set_pipapo_avx2.c#L75

This seems to be a kernel module to deal with filtering IP packets and doing firewall stuff.

---

This doesn't seem all that bad, but when I run my own high-performance software package (same `perf` command, but adding my binary in the end) I get this in the latest version of HotSpot:

[image]

Now HotSpot claims that 30% of the "cycles" correspond to this mysterious function. All the blue in the timeline suggests that the function is indeed everywhere intervening across all my threads.

Now, as it still suggests, this happens in a binary called `nf_tables`. The funny thing is: I recorded this after having blacklisted the kernel modules `nf_tables`, `x_tables` and `ip_tables`. I confirmed this after rebooting that no such kernel modules were present when querying `lsmod`.

It gets extra difficult when I try to open the same perf recording in `perf-report`. I never get to even see it. This makes me believe I actually am missing some flags for `perf report` to tell it to also show those. By now, I have installed the linux kernel image with debug symbols and pointed `perf` to this using `-k`, but that doesn't make a difference. Anyway: how would HotSpot be able to show them without ever having those kernel debug symbols?

I currently have two hypothesis:

1. Hypothesis 1) `perf report` doesn't show those samples, because it filters based on the binary I profiled.
2. Hypothesis 2) This is a visualization bug in how HotSpot attributes cycles/time to recorded samples.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a point where I cannot reproduce this issue. The behavior changed after having installed the kernel image with debug symbols, I think, by following this guide:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Non-built-in_debug_symbol_packages_.28.2A-dbgsym.29

After which I installed the linux kernel debug symbols:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

Now, HotSpot was still showing the weird `nft_pipapo_avx2_scratch_index`. However, after rerecording with `perf` (same command as original question), and reopening the recording in HotSpot, it actually worked. I am now seeing what I expect to see. And a whole bunch of weird unrelated DSOs (dynamic shared objects, such as `nf_tables`, `iwlwifi.ko`, `mac80211.ko`) no longer show up:

[image]

So, I'm now guessing it's a bug in HotSpot or perf not properly communicating through the `perf.data` file what is actually going on. I have no clue why I had to rerecord after installing the debug symbols.